# docker build go project failed

Tags: docker, go

https://github.com/shuimuliang/qnmahjongserver

I tried to build a golang project with Docker. I have followed the steps from this project and successfully build the project by `go build -o qnmahjong` . But when I run `docker build -t qnmahjong` . It gives me `error: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.`
I am not sure is that the output file is invalid or the docker command does not treat the output file as 1 argument.

Comment: Hi, I think you need to add a full stop. You are missing that.  `docker build -t qnmahjong .`  try the code that I wrote, It has a dot at last.

Answer (score 37):

Replace `docker build -t qnmahjong`  with `docker build -t qnmahjong .`

You are missing the "`.`" The dot means you use the Dockerfile in the local directory

This will create a Docker image named qnmahjong based on the instructions in the Dockerfile. You can then run the image using the following command:

```
docker run qnmahjong
```

Comment: Nice answer. I am also missing the . (dot)